# Transcript error in "which are really amazing for reading books"?

Tags: listening

Here's a video transcript from VOA news.
http://www.voanews.com/content/apple-introduces-two-bigger-more-powerful-iphone-models/2444114.html

00:24

> "I think there's a lot of people that got big-screen envy and switched away from Apple towards Android phones with those 5-inch screens, which are really amazing for reading books and looking at your calendar and web-reading.  If Apple can get into that category I think there's a lot of people waiting to switch back," said Ackerman.

He says **blogs** in stead of **books** in "which are really amazing for reading books", right?

Comment: I hear *books*, but I can see why you might think he says *blogs*.  (I'm not sure how to describe it in precise terms, so I'm just posting a comment.)

Comment: It feels to me like he switched words mid-stream. Like he was going to say *blogs* but then remembered that Apple sells iBooks and that he'd better say *books* instead so it came out as a mix of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tech blogger [Dan Ackerman](http://www.danackerman.com/) was born in Buffalo, New York and spent substantial time in the Bronx and New York City. Whatever that means for his dialect and idiolect.

He says **books,** but with a "weird"  pronunciation. Kind of like **boooks** or even like **bugs**.

It's interesting that he is a former radio Disc Jockey. I don't think he speaks with clear enunciation. Some kind of combination of New York talk-a-mile-a-minute with Disc Jockey "cram ten minutes worth of info into the thirty seconds between songs." You can hear a lot more of his way of talking in [this other video blog](http://in.reuters.com/video/2014/09/08/this-is-apples-one-big-shot-for-the-year?videoId=341806162).

Comment: Oops, clearly I didn't get that (I'm from California).